# Wild card Sub-domain using virtual hosts

Tags: apache, subdomain, config, virtualhost

Can someone explain to me how this actually works. This is the code in Apache's httpd.conf file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "somepath"
ServerAlias mobile.mysite.com
ServerName mobile.mysite.com 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "somepath"
ServerAlias *.mysite.com
ServerName mysite.com 
</VirtualHost>
```

I want do something like if its mobile.mysite.com it should go to mobile.mysite.com. If its anything else.mysite.com, then it should go to mysite.com. Does the above code perform the same thing ? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

No, this code does not do any of the mentioned task. You will have to use mod_rewrite for this purpose.

Modify your httpd.conf file to include mod_rewrite.so and then write something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC]
RewriteRule $ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

What the above rewrite rule does is that it checks whether the host name starts with `www` or not, if it does not then it includes `www.` in the hostname and redirects.

You could write a rewrite rule similar to this.

Read more about rewrite rule [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

Comment: Thanks. The thing is I want to point all my sub-domains to mysite.com except the mobile site. So how can I do that ?